# Arduino Due - wireless programming via Xbee

Tags: arduino-due, xbee

I would like to integrate an Arduino Due into a project, which probably will evolve over time and will need some re-programming. Instead of having to disconnect and pull out the Arduino Due out from the enclosure, I was wondering whether it can be set up for wireless programming via an Xbee in a similar way as for the Arduino Fio (like described here: http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardFioProgramming).

Has anyone tried that already or succeeded doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, it is possible I have not tried to do it on an Arduino but I did work something similar with a pic controller. Usually, when we program the board with the firmware file we break the firmware file and send it as multiple packets over the serial com port to be written to on a certain flash memory location on the controller.

In your case, you can try an experiment by using 2 XBee modules that are connected together with the appropriate channel and network ID settings wirelessly. connect one XBee to your computer using a serial to USB cable. On the Arduino side, you have to connect to power it and use the second XBee to connect to it on the UART port. This way the XBee acts as a simple wireless data transfer channel to send and receive data wirelessly (if I am right this should be achievable in the transparent mode on XBee).

One thing to note is to check the Arduino schematic to see how exactly the data over USB is sent to the controller. If it is on UART then this should work straightforward if not then you may have to figure out something else for it.